# pandas: count the non-duplicated elements when using aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have the following code:

```
data_agg_df = data_df.groupby("team", as_index=False).player.agg({"player_set": lambda x: set(list(x)), "player_count": "count"})

data_agg_df
```

Then I noticed the output of `player_count` is the value of `list(x)`, not `set(list(x))`. How do I count the non-duplicated players, i.e. `set(list(x))` here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) to get a count of unique players:

```
data_agg_df = data_df.groupby("team", as_index=False).player.agg({"player_set": "nunique", "player_count": "count"})
```

If you want an array of unique players, use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) instead of `nunique` in the same manner as above.